# Is it okay adding paginated content rel="next" and rel="prev" using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, pagination, seo

I am creating an Umbraco page, where some pages have paginated content (12 articles per page). [According to Google](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/1663744), I need to add previous and next page tags in my `<head>` tag, like so:

```
<link rel="prev" href="?page=2">
<link rel="next" href="?page=4">
```

They can be relative or absolute paths. It does not matter.

Since only *some*  pages have pagination, would it be okay to add these directly to the head tag (appended) through JavaScript? Does Google's crawler care? I'm not sure how I would do this dynamically through my `Master` page (which has the `<head>` tag and so on), because it essentially knows nothing about the current page I am on.